# what is the query to set username and password and pass it in RowMapper

Tags: spring, jdbc

```
public User getUser(String u ,String p) {
    List<User> userList=new ArrayList<User>();
    String sql = "select * from user where username=? and password=?";
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate=new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    userList=jdbcTemplate.query(sql,u,p,new UserRowMapper());
    return userList.get(0);
}
```

where to set u and p so that i can pass it to  the UserRowMapper that gives all the information of user that matches username and password  ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below should work for you,you need to pass the data in the `Object[]` array,like below.

```
User user=jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql,new Object[]{username,password},new UserRowMapper());
```

Comment: as soon as i had posted my question i have tried lot and finally found the answer. ur one is absolute correct ...though it was late but thank u very much for ur post ..keep rocking..